# how to add right border of every 1st elemnt of a div in Css (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with three image per row in Desktop and two on mobile. I want to add border-right of first two image for desktop and first one image in mobile view.

But I could not.

I am getting data/image from database and it can be 20 - 30 per page. 
This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 " >
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `id`  ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('couln not select query');
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 ?>
 <form id="mainMenuItem" action ="#" method="post">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="border:1px solid gray; ">
<a href="#">
<div id="imgProDetail" class="img-responsive">
<div class="proImg">
**<img src="<?=$row['imgurl']?>**" class="img-responsive cat-img">  
 </div>
 <div class="proName">
 <h1 style="text-align:center" class="cat-name">**<?=$row['catName']?**> </h1>
 </div>      
 </div>
</a>
</div>

</form>
<?php }; ?> 
</div>
```

I want it to be displayed like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy6Or.png)

How to do this please.

can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

try `.element:first-child` and `.element:nth-child(2)` for mobile device use media query

Comment: which div have to be written before .element:first-child?  It does not work for me Sir,